# pic16f887 PORTA simple or not?

Tags: microcontroller, c

My project with PIC16F887 has strange behavior that I can't explain. This simple c program (I removed the unimportant part) on a PIC16f887 does something weird. Port A is partly switching on en off with RA1. 
In debug variable (picture at the bottom) you can see that RA0..RA3 and RA5 are actualy low (1us). I must be doing something wrong.

```
#include 
#include 
// CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = INTRC_NOCLKOUT     // Oscillator Selection bits (RC oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF                // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF               // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF
#pragma config CP = OFF                  // FLASH Program Memory Code Protection bits (Code protection off)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF                // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR enabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF                 // Low Voltage In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3/PGM pin has PGM function; low-voltage programming enabled)
#pragma config IESO = ON
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF
#pragma config CPD = OFF                // Data EE Memory Code Protection (Code Protection off)
// CONFIG2
#pragma config BOR4V = BOR21V
#pragma config WRT = OFF
#pragma config DEBUG = ON

#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000

void main()
{
    OSCCONbits.IRCF = 0b111;    //internal osc at 8MHz 
    TRISA = 0;
    //----------------------------main loop --------------------
     while (1) // main loop 
     {
         RA1   = 0;
         PORTA = 0xFF;
     }
}
```

[image: debug image]

Comment: PORTA powers up as analog input (default), not as digital input. Have you set ANSEL to (0) from its default (1)?

Comment: Thank you. Thats it!! I just passed this option as not relavant because of the nature of it and the documentation of microchip saying"The state of the ANSEL bits has no affect on digital output functions..  Weird. Thanx.

Comment: Microchip go on to say that the read-modify-write nature of IO transactions adds much complication when inputs are analog and outputs are digital...it is a bit mind-bending. When set to digital-in & digital-out, IO transactions are *mostly* straightforward.

Comment: I can see now that the Analog inputs where causing the problem. All the other I/O pins where stable. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you do `RA1 = 0;` the PIC reads Port A, clears bit 1 in the value read, then writes the result back to Port A. This is called a 'Read-Modify-Write' operation.

The PIC16F887 does not have separate addresses for I/O output and input, so when reading the port it always gets the pin state, not the output register state. Since you haven't disabled analog I/O on PORTA, all the analog input pins read as 0's. These 0's will be written back to the port's output register when doing a read-modify-write operation.

You can set a pin to output mode while keeping the analog input, but to do bit operations on the port you should keep a 'shadow' copy of the output register in a variable, then change bits in the variable and write it to the port. Alternatively if you know what all the other output bits are you can simply hard-code them into the output value.

The same problem can occur if an output pin is pulled down by external circuitry (eg. a transistor or a 'large' capacitor) and can affect other operations such shifting bits or incrementing the value. If there is any doubt then it is best to avoid read-modify-write operations.

Comment: I never heard of this Read-modify-write procedure. Thanx for the response. Makes it clearer.